# Why java throw errors when trying to assign to other type to variables on runtime?

Tags: java, typescript

I'm just wordering how Java prevent to assign other type on runtime.

For example,
typescript can allow below on runtime

```
let str: string = 'str';  // str can assign other type like number on runtime.
```

But Java throw error.

```
String str = 'str';  // str throw error when trying to assign other type like number on runtime.
```

I know that Typescript's type erased after compiling, but I can't understand how this affect above.

Comment: All languages are different. Java doesn't allow it, period

Comment: Think that I set name type with string on typescript and set name type with int on mysql. In this situation, I want to get type error on typescript run time when I call name column on mysql because of mismatching of type. (I know this is wrong design) But typescript would not throw an error but java would. I just want to what is different between java and javascript. is it just language policy...?

Comment: I know java and javascript is different.. What i want to know is that what happen on low level when we initialize variable and how effect that relation with my question. This is just my doubt and i do not find any questions and answer about this

Comment: Well, typescript is (typically) compiled to javascript, which does not enforce variable types at runtime. Java on the other hand specifies that types have to be enforced by the runtime, and this is done by specifying  what a JVM has to do in that regard.

Comment: Java was designed together with the JVM, while typescript was designed to run on existing ECMA script engines, which limited design choices.

Answer (score 1):

The example you posted uses single-quote characters – `'str'` – like below:

```
String str = 'str';
```

If you compile that, you will see a compiler error like this:

```
java: unclosed character literal
```

If you instead use double-quote characters – `"str"` – it will compile fine:

```
String str = "str";
```

Single-quote characters are allowed for single-character values, so code like below is fine. If you want to use more than one character, you cannot use single-quotes.

```
char a = 'a';
```

If you are inclined for further reading, the Java Langauge Spec describes this in detail in the following two sections:

- [3.10.3 Character Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4)
- [3.10.5 String Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)

Also, you stated *"I'm just wordering how Java prevent to assign other type on runtime"* – this isn't right, as the error above is a compile-time error. It's not possible to produce compiled Java (which you then run) containing `'str'`; you can't compile it in the first place.